# py2exe with lxml ImportError

Tags: python, lxml, py2exe

I have generated a python code "XMLGEN.py". In this script, I have used lxml and codecs modules. I used py2exe to create Windows standalone program with this setup file.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['XMLGEN.py'])
```

The dist folder has been generated without any problem with XMLGEN.exe file. BUT, when I try to run the executable, this is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XMLGEN.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

This procedure works fine for a simple script without importing any lxml module.

I also tried this setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'XMLGEN.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml', 'lxml.etree'],
        }
    }
)
```

But, this time I even could not generate the XMLGEN.exe and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    'includes': ['lxml', 'lxml.etree'],
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Should I put the path lxml.etree.pyx since it is not in the Python27/lib directory?
I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: same issue here… can one help?

Comment: Try `'packages': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],` instead.

Comment: It is not working and the error is exactly same as before.

Comment: You may also need to explicitly import xml package. In my project, I had a problem with xml package which was not automatically packaged into exe.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this import error. egg for my lxml installation is lxml-3.3.1-py2.7.egg-info. It just worked fine to me...